# Gaps and Islands solution in Oracle - use of recursive

Tags: oracle, plsql, group-by

I have a problem that could be easily solved using curser in Oracle. However, I wonder if that could be done using select only. I have 1 data set that contains the following fields: Start, Description, MaximumRow, SequentialOrder.

The data set is ordered by Description, Start, SequentialOrder. This is the data for illustration purpose:

[image]

I would like to get the following results in a different data set
(Start, End, Description) where Start is the minimum of the "Start" field in a set and End is the maximum of the "Start" field in the set. The set is defined by the following rule:
 Total number of rows in the new set does not exceed the maximumrow defined in the previous set and all rows in the new set are ordered by SequentialOrder.

Based on the rule above, I have the following sets:
[image]

So the results I would like to see based on the illustration is

```
12-Jun-15, 14-Jun-15, A
01-Jul-15, 01-Jul-15, A
02-Jul-15, 04-Jul-15, A
01-Aug-15, 16-Aug-15, B
```

If that could be done, please advise. I know we could group by Description but I do not know if we could do further grouping based on MaximumRow and SequentialOrder: As mentioned above, the total row in the subset to be evaluated can not exceed the MaximumRow AND has to be in ordered by SequentialOrder.

I do not think that could be done without using cursor but I ask anyway just in case there is.

I have attached the script to generate the sample above:

```
  CREATE TABLE "TEST" 
   (    "Start" DATE, 
    "Description" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "MaximunRow" NUMBER, 
    "SequentialOrder" NUMBER
   ) 
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into TEST ("Start","Description","MaximunRow","SequentialOrder") values (to_date('12-JUN-15','DD-MON-RR'),'A',3,3);
Insert into TEST ("Start","Description","MaximunRow","SequentialOrder") values (to_date('13-JUN-15','DD-MON-RR'),'A',3,4);
Insert into TEST ("Start","Description","MaximunRow","SequentialOrder") values (to_date('14-JUN-15','DD-MON-RR'),'A',3,5);
Insert into TEST ("Start","Description","MaximunRow","SequentialOrder") values (to_date('01-JUL-15','DD-MON-RR'),'A',3,4);
Insert into TEST ("Start","Description","MaximunRow","SequentialOrder") values (to_date('02-JUL-15','DD-MON-RR'),'A',3,3);
Insert into TEST ("Start","Description","MaximunRow","SequentialOrder") values (to_date('04-JUL-15','DD-MON-RR'),'A',3,4);
Insert into TEST ("Start","Description","MaximunRow","SequentialOrder") values (to_date('01-AUG-15','DD-MON-RR'),'B',2,5);
Insert into TEST ("Start","Description","MaximunRow","SequentialOrder") values (to_date('16-AUG-15','DD-MON-RR'),'B',2,7);
```

Comment: Have you looked at [the model clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2172805)? Also you haven't shown any data or results where the maximum row limit has any effect; your longest sequence run is 3 anyway. Maybe you can show some variations with longer runs and different maximums, and how the groups are affected?

Comment: And what is the maximum number of rows in the first set, since there is no previous set to get that value from?

Comment: @AlexPoole: The maximum number was included in the field MaximumRow

Comment: But you said "Total number of rows in the new set does not exceed the maximumrow defined **in the previous set**". For the first set, starting 12-Jun-15, there is no previous set, so does it have no maximum size, or does it default to its own value? Will that be the same value for all rows that form the set, incidentally?

Comment: So - are you still interested in solutions to this problem, but without using recursive queries? It's not clear - you posted something yesterday, then pulled it back.

Comment: @mathguy: thank you for following it up but I am not sure if this is doable without recursive. So I am pulling it out to reformulate my question better. I realize that I have not been clear in what I was asking. It appears that it is a limitation of sql and not oracle as I do not have issue with oracle. I am going to provide you with a whole set of data with thousand records to illustrate the limitation of sql. No problem with oracle at all.

Comment: The most important questions are: (1) What version of Oracle do you have? Oracle 12.1 and above has the MATCH_RECOGNIZE clause, which can do quick work of such recursive calculations. (2) Where is the MAXIMUMROW coming from? In your examples it is constant for each DESCRIPTION, and if so, then you really don't need recurrence - it can all be done with analytic functions and no recursion.

Comment: I had 11.g and now 12.c. No problem in oracle at all. maximumrow or I should call it the threshold so that the records could not surpass. I am going to formulate my question better tomorrow so that the distinction is clear. I am currently exhausted trying to wrestle with the issue myself but still could not get away with the error in sql.  I would probably need help from more capable guys in here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a variation of a gaps-and-islands problem, with the added complication of the maximum number of rows in each island. This is a bit long-winded but you could start by identifying the groups caused by the sequence order:

```
select t.*,
  row_number() over (partition by "Description" order by "Start") as rn,
  case when lag("SequentialOrder")
    over (partition by "Description" order by "Start") < "SequentialOrder"
    then 1 else 0 end as newblock
from test t
order by "Start";

Start     Description MaximunRow SequentialOrder  RN   NEWBLOCK
--------- ----------- ---------- --------------- --- ----------
12-JUN-15 A                    3               3   1          0
13-JUN-15 A                    3               4   2          1
14-JUN-15 A                    3               5   3          1
01-JUL-15 A                    3               4   4          0
02-JUL-15 A                    3               3   5          0
04-JUL-15 A                    3               4   6          1
01-AUG-15 B                    2               5   1          0
16-AUG-15 B                    2               7   2          1
```

You can then use [a recursive CTE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#BCEJGIBG) (from 11gR2 onwards) based on that:

```
with u as (
  select t.*,
    row_number() over (partition by "Description" order by "Start") as rn,
    case when lag("SequentialOrder")
      over (partition by "Description" order by "Start") < "SequentialOrder"
      then 1 else 0 end as newblock
  from test t
),
r ("Start", "Description", "MaximunRow", "SequentialOrder", rn, blocknum,
  pos, lastmaxrow) as (
  select u."Start", u."Description", u."MaximunRow", u."SequentialOrder", u.rn,
    1, 1, u."MaximunRow"
  from u
  where rn = 1
  union all
  select u."Start", u."Description", u."MaximunRow", u."SequentialOrder", u.rn,
    case when r.pos = r.lastmaxrow or u.newblock = 0
      then r.blocknum + 1 else r.blocknum end,
    case when r.pos = r.lastmaxrow or u.newblock = 0
      then 1 else r.pos + 1 end,
    case when r.pos = r.lastmaxrow or u.newblock = 0
      then r.lastmaxrow else u."MaximunRow" end
  from r
  join u on u."Description" = r."Description" and u.rn = r.rn + 1
)
select * from r
order by "Start";

Start     Description MaximunRow SequentialOrder  RN   BLOCKNUM  POS LASTMAXROW
--------- ----------- ---------- --------------- --- ---------- ---- ----------
12-JUN-15 A                    3               3   1          1    1          3
13-JUN-15 A                    3               4   2          1    2          3
14-JUN-15 A                    3               5   3          1    3          3
01-JUL-15 A                    3               4   4          2    1          3
02-JUL-15 A                    3               3   5          3    1          3
04-JUL-15 A                    3               4   6          3    2          3
01-AUG-15 B                    2               5   1          1    1          2
16-AUG-15 B                    2               7   2          1    2          2
```

This is assigning a `blocknum` to each row, with that starting at one for each description in the anchor member, and being incremented in the recursive member either if the `newblock` is zero (indicating a sequence break) or the number of members in the block is the previous maximum. (I may not have the logic for 'previous maximum' quite right as it isn't clear in the question.)

You can then group by the description and the generated block number:

```
with u as (
  select t.*,
    row_number() over (partition by "Description" order by "Start") as rn,
    case when lag("SequentialOrder")
      over (partition by "Description" order by "Start") < "SequentialOrder"
      then 1 else 0 end as newblock
  from test t
),
r ("Start", "Description", "MaximunRow", "SequentialOrder", rn, blocknum,
  pos, lastmaxrow) as (
  select u."Start", u."Description", u."MaximunRow", u."SequentialOrder", u.rn,
    1, 1, u."MaximunRow"
  from u
  where rn = 1
  union all
  select u."Start", u."Description", u."MaximunRow", u."SequentialOrder", u.rn,
    case when r.pos = r.lastmaxrow or u.newblock = 0
      then r.blocknum + 1 else r.blocknum end,
    case when r.pos = r.lastmaxrow or u.newblock = 0
      then 1 else r.pos + 1 end,
    case when r.pos = r.lastmaxrow or u.newblock = 0
      then r.lastmaxrow else u."MaximunRow" end
  from r
  join u on u."Description" = r."Description" and u.rn = r.rn + 1
)
select min(r."Start") as "Start", max(r."Start") as "End", r."Description"
from r
group by r."Description", r.blocknum
order by r."Description", r.blocknum;

Start     End       Description
--------- --------- -----------
12-JUN-15 14-JUN-15 A          
01-JUL-15 01-JUL-15 A          
02-JUL-15 04-JUL-15 A          
01-AUG-15 16-AUG-15 B
```

Your sample data doesn't trigger the maximum rows break as you don't have any sequences longer than 3 anyway. With some additional data:

```
Insert into TEST ("Start","Description","MaximunRow","SequentialOrder") values (to_date('15-JUN-15','DD-MON-RR'),'A',3,7);
Insert into TEST ("Start","Description","MaximunRow","SequentialOrder") values (to_date('16-JUN-15','DD-MON-RR'),'A',3,8);
Insert into TEST ("Start","Description","MaximunRow","SequentialOrder") values (to_date('17-JUN-15','DD-MON-RR'),'A',3,10);
Insert into TEST ("Start","Description","MaximunRow","SequentialOrder") values (to_date('18-JUN-15','DD-MON-RR'),'A',3,12);
Insert into TEST ("Start","Description","MaximunRow","SequentialOrder") values (to_date('19-JUN-15','DD-MON-RR'),'A',3,13);
```

the same query gets:

```
Start     End       Description
--------- --------- -----------
12-JUN-15 14-JUN-15 A          
15-JUN-15 17-JUN-15 A          
18-JUN-15 19-JUN-15 A          
01-JUL-15 01-JUL-15 A          
02-JUL-15 04-JUL-15 A          
01-AUG-15 16-AUG-15 B
```

so you can see it's splitting on sequence change *and* on hitting three rows in the block.

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2ab3b/1).

You could get away with just the recursive CTE, and not the previous intermediate one, by comparing the sequential order directly in the case statements instead of using `newblock`; but having `rn` to find the next row is easier than trying to find the next date as they aren't contiguous.

Comment: Wow! the use of recursive is awesome! Is there any restriction on the recursive? My illustration is just a simplified version of a more complex data set. How many level of recursive can Oracle sustain?

Comment: @user1205746 - you're only limited by available memory as far as I'm aware. And you have to be on a version that supports it, obviously. There are some functional restrictions listed in the doc I linked to. Hopefully this will give you a starting point for your complex data...

Comment: The script is very slick! I had to use cursor to do the job before your solution and it was not elegant at all to say the least. This is a much much cleaner way to get the job done and I thought it could not be done this way! Awesome!