# i have requirement in which column value need to break into two column rangefrom and rangeto

Tags: oracle

I have requirement in which msn column need to break into rangefrom and rangeto
table

```
num    msn    date

1ab    5       25/2/2019
1ab    7       25/2/2019
1ab    8       25/2/2019
1ac    8       25/4/2019
1ad    9       25/5/2019
1ad    10       25/5/2019
1ad    11       25/5/2019
```

output should like this if msn is not continuous then same value goes to rangefrom and rangeto if continuous then min value will go to rangefrom and max value will go rangeto based on date and num

```
num   rangefrom  rangeto   date
1ab     5         5        25/2/2019
1ab     7         8        25/2/2019
1ad     9         11        25/4/2019
```

Comment: What happened to `1ac`? Shouldn't there be a `1ac | 8 | 8 | 25/4/2019` record in the output? What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: yes..i forgot to add 1ac | 8 | 8 | 25/4/2019....i am new to DB . So please let me know how to break.

Comment: That helps for sure. This feels very much like a "gaps and islands" problem. These can get a little ugly to think through and I wish I had the time to work this one up. [It's very similar in nature to this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30803021/gaps-and-islands-solution-in-oracle-use-of-recursive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `LAG()` and `LEAD()` window functions and a `CTE`:

```
with cte as (
 select t.*,
    case when "msn" - lag("msn") over (partition by "num", "date" order by "msn") = 1 then 0 else 1 end isfrom,
    case when lead("msn") over (partition by "num", "date" order by "msn") - "msn" = 1 then 0 else 1 end isto
  from tablename t 
)
select c1."num", c1."msn" rangefrom, min(c2."msn") rangeto, c1."date"
from cte c1 inner join cte c2
on c2."num" = c1."num" and c2."date" = c1."date" 
and (
  (c1.isfrom = 1 and c2.isto = 1 and c1."msn" < c2."msn")
  or
  (c1.isfrom = 1 and c1.isto = 1 and c1."msn" = c2."msn")
) 
group by c1."num", c1."msn", c1."date"
order by c1."num", c1."msn", c1."date"
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e6dd053ab5f65aa3423987d675988d06).
Results:

```
> num | RANGEFROM | RANGETO | date     
> :-- | --------: | ------: | :--------
> 1ab |         5 |       5 | 25/2/2019
> 1ab |         7 |       8 | 25/2/2019
> 1ac |         8 |       8 | 25/4/2019
> 1ad |         9 |      11 | 25/5/2019
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try below query -

```
SELECT NUM, MIN(MSN), MAX(MSN), DTE
FROM (SELECT NUM, TRIM(MSN) MSN, DTE, TRIM(MSN)-ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DTE, TRIM(MSN)) SEQNUM
      FROM T)
GROUP BY NUM, SEQNUM, DTE
ORDER BY NUM;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b245c40e08e2b9506c9a451a9469272b) is the demo1.
[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=11661a2948a53810cf4681b16287f2b6) is the demo2.

Comment: Thanks for your response but unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: Did you refer the fiddle in Demo? Its perfectly working fine there. Please post some more sample data or authentic data if possible if it doesn't work in your system.

Comment: I have done in same way...but unfortunately it does not work. I will add some simple data tmrw...its work partially but not like  demo fiddle.

Comment: i have sent the details in your personal email with sample data...

Comment: You have spaces in you MSN column. After removing those spaces, and updating the query little bit, I think this is working as expected now.

Comment: i Think so but data already availabe with space then i need to call the trim function to remove the space in specific column or other function also avilable bec I can not change the value of table...

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: even after  adding the  Trim(msn)  nfortunately it does not work

Comment: But it is working on fiddle with your production data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205686/discussion-between-ranjan-prabhat-and-ankit-bajpai).