# Oracle SQL - need help converting from one date value EFF_DT to a date range of START_EFF_DT and END_EFF_DT with unique criteria

Tags: sql, oracle, crystal-reports

I've hit the wall with this query and i'm asking for any assistance on this one

Background:
I need to create a query that identifies all the "Unpaid" work days based on the data that is available in our Oracle database

Our Time & Labour tracking data contains only 1 date column (EFF_DT) representing "work date"

A simplified version of the raw table looks like below:

| EEID | WORK_DT | PAYCODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 2022/03/01 | UNPAID |
| 1111 | 2022/03/02 | REG_WORK |
| 1111 | 2022/03/03 | REG_WORK |
| 1111 | 2022/03/04 | UNPAID |
| 1111 | 2022/03/05 | UNPAID |
| 1111 | 2022/03/06 | SICK |
| 1111 | 2022/03/07 | SICK |
| 1111 | 2022/03/08 | UNPAID |
| 1111 | 2022/03/09 | UNPAID |
| 1111 | 2022/03/10 | UNPAID |

What I need to do is to filter for only the "UNPAID" rows and then I need to identify the "range" of start/end work dates of the unpaid leave

So the expected results would need to look like the following:

| EEID | START_EFF_DT | END_EFF_DT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 2022/03/01 | 2022/03/01 |
| 1111 | 2022/03/04 | 2022/03/05 |
| 1111 | 2022/03/08 | 2022/03/10 |

How should I approach designing this SQL for the crystal report that needs to be created?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: For a fixed EEID, are the dates ALWAYS a complete sequence? Or can there be gaps - for example there are rows for 3/25 and 3/28 but not for the two days in between? And if there can be gaps, how should that be handled? If "UNPAID" on both 3/25 and 3/28, and no rows for the dates in between?

Comment: This is known as the Gaps and Islands problem. See relevant post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30803021/gaps-and-islands-solution-in-oracle-use-of-recursive

Comment: @mathguy - there are certainly date gaps in between the date range (long weekends would generate such a date gap)
In that scenario, as long as the paycode before and after the gap are both UNPAID, then it is still considered a consecutive string of dates

ie:
3/24 - unpaid
3/25 - unpaid
3/28 - unpaid
3/29 - unpaid

The report should output:
EEID: 1111; Start_Eff_Dt: 3/24; End_Eff_Dt 3/29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For users on older versions of Oracle Database (before version 12.1), who cannot use the `match_recognize` clause, here is a solution using just analytic functions and a very nice method for identifying gaps and islands, known as the "fixed differences" or "tabibito-san" method. The trick is the creation of the additional grouping expressions, labeled `grp`, in the helper subquery (which for ease of reading I set off in a `with` clause).

```
with
  prep as (
    select eeid, work_dt, paycode,
           row_number() over (partition by eeid          order by work_dt) 
         - row_number() over (partition by eeid, paycode order by work_dt) 
           as grp
    from   time_labor
  )
select eeid, min(work_dt) as start_eff_dt, max(work_dt) as end_eff_dt
from   prep
group  by eeid, paycode, grp
having paycode = 'UNPAID'
order  by eeid, start_eff_dt
;
```

The sample data (for testing) and the output from this query can be found in the other answer, which uses `match_recognize` (Oracle versions >= 12.1 only)

Comment: amazing!
thank you @mathguy ... this SQL sol'n is exactly what I was looking for to complete this report

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 12.1 and higher, you can use `match_recognize` for a wide variety of pattern-matching problems.

Test data:

```
create table time_labor (eeid number, work_dt date, paycode varchar2(10));

alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy/mm/dd';

insert into time_labor (eeid, work_dt, paycode)
    select 1111, to_date('2022/03/01'), 'UNPAID'   from dual union all
    select 1111, to_date('2022/03/02'), 'REG_WORK' from dual union all
    select 1111, to_date('2022/03/03'), 'REG_WORK' from dual union all
    select 1111, to_date('2022/03/04'), 'UNPAID'   from dual union all
    select 1111, to_date('2022/03/05'), 'UNPAID'   from dual union all
    select 1111, to_date('2022/03/06'), 'SICK'     from dual union all
    select 1111, to_date('2022/03/07'), 'SICK'     from dual union all
    select 1111, to_date('2022/03/08'), 'UNPAID'   from dual union all
    select 1111, to_date('2022/03/09'), 'UNPAID'   from dual union all
    select 1111, to_date('2022/03/10'), 'UNPAID'   from dual
;

commit;
```

Query and output:

```
select eeid, start_eff_dt, end_eff_dt
from   time_labor
match_recognize(
  partition by eeid
  order     by work_dt
  measures  first(work_dt) as start_eff_dt,
            last (work_dt) as   end_eff_dt
  pattern   ( unpaid+ )
  define    unpaid as paycode = 'UNPAID'
);

EEID  START_EFF_DT  END_EFF_DT
----  ------------  ------------
1111  2022/03/01    2022/03/01
1111  2022/03/04    2022/03/05
1111  2022/03/08    2022/03/10
```

The `match_recognize` machinery partitions the input rows and orders them within each partition according to the `partition by` and `order by` clauses. It looks for matches of the pattern `unpaid+`, meaning one or more consecutive rows classified as `unpaid`, where that classification is defined in the `define` clause. (Here `unpaid` is simply my choice of name for this classifier; it seems like a reasonable choice, but it could be called anything else that is a valid identifier, like `x` or `abc_2902`). `match_recognize` returns one row per match by default, with the additional calculated expressions from the `measures` clause.

Comment: thanks for sending me down the rabbit hole to learn about match_recognize() and the concept of "gap & island" problems. I did learn a bit from reading up on it yesterday
Unfortunately, the database we're using is not Oracle 12.1 :(
Therefore, I will need to find another method to achieve my desired results

Comment: @Tommy - if your database is that old (more than four versions behind the current version), then you should state that very clearly in your question. What **is** your version? Different solutions are possible in different versions. (As an aside, I would upgrade to at least version 12.1 even just for `match_recognize`, which is an exceptionally powerful tool for a lot of problems.)

Comment: I don't have much access to this database, it's provided by our 3rd party and I have read-only access. I confirmed with them today that it's still on Oracle 11.... As slick as the sol'n that you provided, I'm going to have to find another way to achieve this :(

Comment: @Tommy - In Oracle 11.2 (and earlier) you can use a very nice method known as the "fixed differences" or "tabibito-san" method, I will post a separate answer to show how.